# Read in optional sheets from Excel into R with an or operator

Tags: r, excel

I have a folder that contains thousands of Excel workbooks (.xlsx). Half of the workbooks have a sheet called `Data` and half the sheets have a sheet called `Changes`. Both these sheets contain the same type of information they are just labeled differently. There is no reason or order to why some are labeled `Changes` and others `Data`.

Currently, I read in all sheets with this code

```
myfiles <- list()
temp = list.files(pattern="*.xls")
myfiles = lapply(temp, function(x){as.data.frame(read_excel(x,sheet = 
"Data"))})
```

But this only reads in the sheets with the `Data` designation.

What I want to do is something like:

```
 myfiles = lapply(temp, function(x){as.data.frame(read_excel(x,sheet = 
 "Changes" || sheet = "Data"))})
```

If I try to load all the workbooks as a whole with

```
myfiles = lapply(temp, function(x){loadworkbook(x)})
```

I get an error about GC overhead limit exceeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can pass an `or` statement to an argument in that way. One solution is to read in the sheet names, search for `"data"` and if it is there, read the `"data"` sheet and if not read the `"changes"` sheet. Here I define a function `read_excel_if` that performs this check for a single file, then I `map` this function to all files in your `temp` variable and then `reduce` all the files into a single dataframe using `bind_rows` - skip this step if you just want a list of `dataframes`.

```
 library(readxl)
 library(purrr)
 library(dplyr)

read_excel_if <- function(file_path) {

  sheets <- excel_sheets(file_path)
  if ("data" %in% sheets) {
    df <- read_excel(file_path, sheet = "data")
  } else {
    df <- read_excel(file_path, sheet = "changes")
  }
  df
}

temp %>% map(read_excel_if) %>% reduce(bind_rows)
```